# Unable to resolve identifier socketmanager with (swift3 xcode9 iOS)

Tags: ios, sockets, socket.io, swift3.2, xcode9.2

I am trying to implement **Socket.IO-Client-Swift** using this [socket.io library](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift). But due to this error *Unable to resolve identifier socketmanager* I am unable to implement this library. I am using xcode 9 and swift 3.2.2.

```
    let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://localhost:8080")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
    let socket = manager.defaultSocket

    socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
        print("socket connected")
    }

    socket.on("client balance change") {data, ack in

        guard let cur = data[0] as? Double else { return }
        socket.emitWithAck("canUpdate", cur).timingOut(after: 0) {data in
            socket.emit("update", ["amount": cur + 2.50])
        }
        ack.with("Got your currentAmount", "dude")

    }

    socket.connect()
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace  SocketManager  with this

```
let socket: SocketIOClient = SocketIOClient(socketURL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8080")! as URL)
```